# 240 to 120 for bedroom outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

So I am redoing a very old house that had two central heat and air units. One of the units was discontinued and is no longer in use. there is a 240v breaker next to it. my question is can I put a new breaker in that box and use it as a 120v for some outlets in a bedroom. Thanks for any constructive help.[image]

Comment: There are legal ways and illegal ways to do this. What is the number and color of wires in the box? Editing and adding a picture would be best.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the breaker box in question please?

Comment: What brand is the breaker box? Some are not safe (zinsco, federal), if it's an unsafe box, best to just replace it entirely.  Small sub-panels aren't very expensive.

Comment: Yes, we'd need to see the exact equipment you have on the wall.  Preferably turn the supply breaker off and pull the covers if possible.  Remember inside a main panel, even with the main breaker off, parts are still zappy.  Once I bumped the main breaker handle and switched it off by accident and put myself in pitch black. I *couldn't* turn it back on because of the risk of touching hot parts; I had to go get a flashlight.

Comment: With most 240v breakers you have 2 conductors and a ground. If black white and ground so yes you probably can but more information will be needed,

Comment: Is there any labeling visible on the inside of the door for the breaker box in the question?

Comment: Ok. So it wont let me comment on any of your responses. I had an electrician friend that i haven't seen in a long time come by and he looked at it and said it was Easy. He walked me through it and here's what we did. The black and red are both independent 120 volt supplies and the Black and white as everyone knows is the neutral and ground. we put in two independent 20 amp breakers, and the neutral and grounds went on the ground bar. I also cleaned out the box. It works like gangbusters. It was exactly how Lucky Joestar said. Thank you all for your comments and your help. I know it seems small

Comment: Instead of "thanking " @Lucky Joestar, put a check mark next to his answer to accept it. Glad this site helped.

Comment: Great that you have a 4-wire feed. You could do it right. It's not. It is **incorrect to have both the neutral and ground on the same bar for a sub-panel for something like 40 years.** The neutral should be isolated from ground, and the ground (only) should be electrically tied to the case.

Comment: Do you know what make the breaker box in question is at least?

Comment: Hi! You were unable to leave this as a comment because you have two accounts, one unregistered used to ask the question and a registered one that posted this. Please consider [merging them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Chances are that you have a white wire connected to one of the terminals of the old 240-volt breaker, and you can repurpose it to neutral. When you put in the new 120-volt breaker, connect the black wire to the breaker terminal and the white to the neutral bus bar, removing any black tape on the white wire. Replace the 240-volt receptacles with 120-volt receptacles.

Comment: They may have a 4 wire feed to the existing subpanel...

Comment: I see your point. In that case, the red wire can simply be left disconnected.

Comment: a 4wire system on a very old house not likely! the answer is correct the only thing that was not discussed was the size of the breaker, 120v circuits won’t be larger than 20 amps, this requires 12 awg or larger wire so if the existing wiring is 12awg or larger one hot on the breaker as the answer stated one neutral and one ground would be code compliant today  if 14 awg it would be a 15 amp breaker +

Comment: I just now saw the added photo. You can use the wires, but that panel does look like it has seen better days. Maybe replacing it would be a good idea.